# What is the physical meaning of Riemann normal Coordinates?

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, geodesics

It's a beginner's question and hopefully not to trivial for this forum: The frame of [Riemann normal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates) (RNC) with regard to a point $P$ in a given metric $g$ is often said to be the reference system of a freely falling point in $P$ at the center of this new coordinates. I thought, that I finally understood it, but now I have doubts again: Yes, a free falling object follows a geodesics, and in order to be in a system of inertia my coordinate system must move along such geodesics, at least in the point under consideration. But now, through a given Point there is more than just one geodesic...In earths "homogeneous" gravitational field we can "remove" gravity by using a coordinate system, moving on a "curve of free fall". But this curve is not unique, since we can use a fall in z-direction as well as a parabola in x-z: Both frames are inertial systems. So what would be RNC in this special case and what is their meaning in general since an infinite set of possible geodesics pass through a given point. The only special thing I would see is, that in RNC the point of reference is momentarily at rest (at t=0). Is there some other important aspect I have overseen?

Answer (score 0):

The Physical significance of the Riemann normal coordinates around a point $p$ is that it contemplates all possible inertial paths that cross $p$. If you want, they parametrize all possible inertial trajectories that can be undergone by a particle that starts its motion at $p$.

Not only that, but for events that are spacelike separated from $p$ the Riemann normal coordinates also contemplate all the possible rest spaces of the event $p$, given its motion.

If you are interested in the coordinates adapted to a $trajectory$ rather than a $point$, I recommend you check the Fermi normal coordinates. An Excellent reference is [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.0529).